# VBA excel change cell with different value

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to replace a cell that have same number and replace it with diffrent value. Like 1846120 have two row in the excel. I want to change one of them to 5 and the other one to 10. How ?

```
  Public Sub ersatt()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            For i = 1 To 10000
                Select Case ws.Cells(i, 1)
                Case 1741568, 1741984, 1741985, 2267661, 2452546, 2452544, 2239671, 2515828, 2254875, 2553829, 2147721, 2609859, 2055238, 2296699, 2611432
                    ws.Cells(i, 9) = "0"
                Case 1893055, 1868157, 1893055
                    ws.Cells(i, 9) = "=8*F2"
                Case 1846120
                   ws.Cells(i, 9) = "=((F2-90)*29+(90*25))"
                End Select
            Next
        Next ws
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

to write the value of a cell, write ...Cells(row, column).Value = X
If you want to write a numeric variable, write

```
 ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = 0
```

without the "". If your write "0" the cell will contain the string '0', writing the above code will write the numeric value 0. This becomes important when you write variables.
Same goes for the argument of "Select Case"

Also write Next **i** after the line that says "End Select"

Comment: Can you edit it in the code, I didn't understand. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to use **"Option Explicit"** at the top of your code.also if you want to get cell value use **.value**.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ersatt()

      Dim ws As Worksheet
      Dim i As Long

      For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

          For i = 1 To 10000
                With ws
                    Select Case .Cells(i, 1)
                    Case 1741568, 1741984, 1741985, 2267661, 2452546, 2452544, 2239671, 2515828, 2254875, 2553829, 2147721, 2609859, 2055238, 2296699, 2611432
                        ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "0"
                    Case 1893055, 1868157, 1893055
                        .Cells(i, 9).Value = 8 * .Range("F2").Value
                    Case 1846120
                       .Cells(i, 9).Value = ((.Range("F2").Value) - 90) * (29 + (90 * 25))
                    End Select
                End With

          Next i

      Next ws

  End Sub
```